# Sizeof Reports Improper Size of Type-defined Structure - C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, struct, typedef, sizeof

My application has a defined structure:

```
typedef struct zsSysVersionMsg_tag
{
    WORD cmd;
    BYTE len;
} zsSysVersionMsg_t;
```

I would expect `sizeof(zsSysVersionMsg_t)` to evaluate to 3.  However, when I run my application it evaluates to 4.  Can someone explain why this is?  (I really need it to evaluate to 3.)  Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment How to make it evaluate to 3 also appears in this article

Comment: Be aware that data alignment techniques are platform-specific.

Comment: Standard says it will evaluate to >= wizeof(WORD) + sizeof(BYTE), not necesarrily exactly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most platforms will "align" and "pad" structures so that they begin and end exactly on a word boundary.  This is done to improve memory performance.

Assuming you are on Windows, you can set your own alignment.  In your case, you want to align on single bytes, so do this:

```
#pragma pack( push, 1 )
typedef struct zsSysVersionMsg_tag
{
    WORD cmd;
    BYTE len;
} zsSysVersionMsg_t;
#pragma pack( pop )
```

Comment: Thanks, John.  Does the `#pragma pack( push, 1 )` indicate single-byte alignment, or does it simply add a single byte of padding?  I ask because I recognize the `push` and `pop` instructions from my assembly days, and (not that I doubt you, but) I don't see how these instructions will help.  Also, do I need to put these `pragma` statements around every type-definition, or can I do something like `pragrma, typedef, typedef, typedef, pragma`?

Comment: the `1` tells it to align on a 1-byte boundary.  `push` and `pop` do what you think.  they push and pop the previous alignment.